# Proving that $\exists f: \mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$, biholomorphic, which maps $z_1$ to $w_1$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, holomorphic-functions

Consider a pair of points, $z_1, w_1 \in \mathbb{D}$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc centred at the origin. Is it sufficient to argue that $f(z)=z+a$ (for $a\in \mathbb{C}$) is biholomorphic, since $\exists a$, such that $z_1 + a=w_1$ for any $z_1$ and $w_1$? Or is there a more elegant way to prove this?

Would appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map might not be a map from the unit disc to itself. To prove your original statement, consider the map $w \mapsto \frac{z_0-w}{1-\bar{z_0}w}$ which is a biholomorphism on the disc sending the point $z_0$ to $0$.

Comment: Can you please clarify how does this map send $z_0$ to $0$? Also, what do you think about $f(z)=\frac{w_1}{z_1}z$? I know it's not general, but it does the job for $z_1\to w_1$.

Comment: Could it be that your map isn't quite correct? I know that for an $\alpha\in \mathbb D$ the similiar map $$\eta_\alpha(z)=\frac{\alpha-z}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$$ has the properties that $\eta_\alpha\in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb D)$, $\eta_\alpha(\mathbb D)\subset \mathbb D$, $\eta_\alpha\circ\eta_\alpha=\operatorname{id}$ and most notably $\eta_\alpha(\alpha)=0$ as well as $\eta_\alpha(0)=\alpha$.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Can you please illustrate with an example how $\eta_a(z)$ moves $z$ to $\alpha$? I don't see the connection as yet.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic that is probably the correct one.

Comment: @sequence substitute $\alpha$ into this map. The numerator becomes zero (and the denominator well defined), so the image of $\alpha$ under this map is $0$. Let $\beta$ be the point you want to map $\alpha$ to, then $\eta_{\beta}\circ \eta_{\alpha}$ sends $\alpha$ to $\beta$. To see this, just substitute $\alpha$ into this composition. 

The map you proposed in the comments does not work in general because it is not in general a biholomorphic map on the unit disc (consider norms)..

Comment: @fixedp why do we need to consider $\eta_\beta \circ \eta_\alpha$, and not just some single function (not a composition of functions)? Can we instead make a single function to do this task? For $f(z)=\frac{w_1}{z_1}z$, why is it not biholomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$? It's analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ and its derivative is nonzero on $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: @sequence it is easier to see what's happening (and of course the proof also becomes easier). That said, a composition of functions is itself a single function.

Comment: @fixedp why do we need $\bar{\alpha}$ in the denominator? Why can't the denominator be $1$ or anything else, such that it is not zero for $\eta_\alpha(\alpha)$?

Comment: @sequence: The problem with your map is that is isn't generally a map from $\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$. Sure, it's analytic and does what you want, but if you consider the case that $w_1 = 1/2$ and $z_1 = 1/4$, then you have $f(z) = 2z$, which doesn't map $\mathbb{D}$ into itself.

Comment: @SimonRose but if $f(z) = \eta_{w_1}(z)$, then $f(z_1) = \frac{w_1-z_1}{1-\bar{w_1}z_1}$. Can you please clarify how this function maps $z_1$ to $w_1$?

Comment: @sequence It does not. $\eta_{z_1}$ sends $z_1$ to $0$ and vice versa. $\eta_{w_1}$ sends $0$ to $w_1$ and vice versa. Ergo, $\eta_{w_1}\circ \eta_{z_1}$ sends $z_1$ to $0$ to $w_1$. I feel a lot of your questions can be answered if you sat down and prove the statements given by Christian Ivicevic.